# querying a MySQL table from VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I made my software in vb.net and connected it with MySQL databse and using phpmyadmin I have create a table update and a column version.

In the version column I have inserted the link of version.txt

I want that my update library which is updateVB will get the link of version.txt from the database from that table....

```
Updatevb1.checkforupdate("Text file where your version is stated (URL)", 
                         "Current Version", 
                         "URL of executable updater (SFX Archive), 
                         "Username for FTP", "Password for FTP", 
                          showUI As Boolean)
```

I want to get every of these information like: Text file version URL, current version, URL of executable update etc.

How can this be done?

```
conn = New MySqlConnection(ServerString)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT FROM updater"
        Dim data As MySqlDataReader
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command.CommandText = sqlquery
        command.Connection = conn
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        data = command.ExecuteReader
        While data.Read()
            If data.HasRows() Then
                Dim vlink As String = data(1).ToString
                Dim dlink As String = data(2).ToString
                Dim ftpu As String = data(3).ToString
                Dim ftpp As String = data(4).ToString
            End If
        End While
        UpdateVB1.checkforupdate("vlink", "0.0.9", "dlink", "ftpu", "ftpp", showUI:=True)
        data.Close()
        conn.Close()
```

Comment: You can't ask for some code just like that. You need to ask a question about a problem you have, show others what have you tried and why it's not working.

Comment: OwerFlov I have corrected the errors in my question....

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your SQL statement isn't specifying any columns.

Supply the list of columns that you want to consume.

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT vlink, dlink, ftpu, dtpp FROM updater"
```

Comment: I have corrected the first problem and specified the columns...but it is still not working....what is the second problem???